# How to remove standard "New Case" button for specific record type?

Tags: case

I've a case record type "Quality Report Cases". We have around 12 different case record types. I've a custom link "New Quality Report" set up which takes the user to VF page used for creating Quality report cases. I want to hide the standard New Case, Change owner buttons only for this specific record type. I tried removing by editing case list view but it is removing for all the other record types as well.

How do I get rid of them just for this record type?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** with what you are trying to attempt.

"New" is an operation which is specific to an Object, i.e., if you can create the records of a specific object or not based on your profile permissions.

List views are configured on the "Tabs" associated to that Object's Search Layout (List View) and does not have anything to do with the specific record types. If you remove a button there, it removes it for that Object altogether from any list views that you configure.

Using out of the box features, you just cannot remove the button specific to a record type. If you at all don't want to create a specific record type, just remove the access to that record type from the profile and that should work.